# AS3 SampleDataEvent from microphone

Tags: actionscript-3, events, microphone

I'm writing a recorder for website with flash using the `flash.events.SampleDataEvent` from the Microphone. But there is one strange thing:
At the beginning the `SampleEvent` occurs approximately every second. That's really slow. But after waiting a while in front of the browser and starting it again, it's very fast. 
So 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to influence the time between the events
2. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of strange. There's no way to tell the event when to dispatch. It just gets triggered when the microphone has sound data in the buffer. For some reason, it doesn't seem like your microphone is recording very much data at first. Try adjusting Microphone.gain and also Microphone.rate. Higher gain will amplify what you are recording to hopefully trigger the event faster and increasing the rate will give you more samples per event.